# фильтр товаров с href на javascript

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на элемент, который является фильтром на сайте:

```
> <a rel="nofollow" href="javascript:qsn.set('classtype','of',1);">nur
> Angebote</a>
```

Сайт перезагружается, ссылка не меняется, но фильтр применется и отсеивается часть товаров.

Кто нибуть может пояснить, что происходит после нажатия кнопки фильтра с передаваемыми парамтерами?

Comment: Происходит аякс запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, речь идёт о веб-приложении, которое сохраняет состояние на сервере. При нажатии на элемент происходит следующее:

1. Метод *set* отправляет на сервер ajax-запрос с параметрами фильтра.
2. Сервер обновляет состояние.
3. Клиент получает ответ об успешном выполнении запроса и обновляет страницу.
4. Сервер формирует и возвращает страницу с новым списком товаров, соответствующим параметрам фильтра.